# How to identify google maps marker on the map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a list of google maps markers as html links next to a google map. I have the function that is triggered when I click on the link. Marker ID is passed to this function.

My question is - when I have 100 markers, I want somehow IDENTIFY the clicked marker on the map. Some sort of ripple effect that would go away from the marker.

please advice what are my possible options so I could develop appropriate solution

Example: 100 markers already on the map. I also have 100 names on the left. Each name corresponds to each marker. When I click the name, I want the marker that belongs to that name somehow "blink" or identify itself in some other way among other markers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ripple effect would be quite complicated, possibly involving positioning of a ['GroundOverlay'](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GroundOverlay) object centered around the marker you wish to highlight.

If your goal is just to be able to highlight the marker, perhaps playing a simple animation using ['Marker.setAnimation(animationObject)'](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker). You could perhaps using ['Animation.BOUNCE'](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Animation) to highlight the marker?

Comment: How would I do that? I have the function:
                function overTheFleetBox(sn){
                    var mar = all_markers[sn];
                    mar.setAnimation.BOUNCE;
                }

Answer (score 2):

before the markers was pin on the map
you need to set a global markers variable

```
var gb.markers = [];
```

while you create each marker need to push into global marker array

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  // other stuff
  'id': marker.id
});
```

after you done with assign function to marker, push it into global var

```
gb.markers.push(marker);
```

make sure when you click on marker will get marker id
and loop the global markers or make marker array with id as index

Comment: Yes, I got this, I store markers in hasmap. What I need to do, is to VISUALLY IDENTIFY the marker on the map among other markers.

Comment: can you try this map.getBounds().contains(marker.getPosition())